# Assertion for matching driver.getcurrenturl () and expected url reports pass when urls dont match

Tags: java, authentication, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber-jvm

I am new to Selenium and am trying a selenium/cucumber/junit framework as trial framework. I have a simple test to log into a website and pass/fail the test based on whether the actual URL matches the expected URL after login. When purposely make the actual and expected urls not match, the cucumber report shows pass.

My test calls an Assertions file with code:

```
public static boolean  validatePageURL(WebDriver driver, String expectedURL)
{
    boolean result=false;
        if(driver.getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(expectedURL));
        {

            result=true;
        }
        return result;
```

If I comment out the If statement the correct Boolean result is returned. If I change the "result=true" to "result=false" the cucumber report shows fail.

Here is my steps code:

```
@When("^User enters username$")
public void user_enters_username() throws Throwable{
    login =new LoginPage(driver);
    login.enterUsername("user1");
}

@And("^User enters password$")
public void user_enters_password() throws Throwable {
          login.enterPassword("P123456");
}

@And("^User clicks login button$")
public void user_clicks_login_button() throws Throwable {
   login.clickLoginButton();
}

@Then("^User is logged in successfully$")
public void user_is_logged_in_successfully() throws Throwable {

Assertions.assertTrue(Compare3.validatePageURL(driver, "incorrecturl"));
```

My Assertion File has:

```
public class Compare3 {
public static boolean  validatePageURL(WebDriver driver, String expectedURL)
{
    boolean result=false;
        if(driver.getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(expectedURL));
        {

            result=true;
        }
        return result;
```

In the scenario above, I want the cucumber report to show a fail as the actual and expected urls do not match.

I can make the report show fail buy commenting out the if statement or changing the result value in the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition is not working as there is a terminator `;` after the `if` condition, so the code never really goes into if condition and the `boolean` value never changes.
You just need to remove the `;` which is present after your `if` condition and your code would work fine.

```
if(driver.getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase(expectedURL)){
    result=true;
}
```